# Mathematical operation on subscriber ROS node

Tags: python, ros, rospy

I am receiving data from a topic,
I subscribed to this topic in a separate node
I want to do some mathematical operation on these data but I get an error
this is the code

```
def __init__(self):

rospy.init_node('extreme_values', annonymous=True)
self.x= rospy.subscriber('x_values', float32, callback)
self.y= rospy.subscriber('y_values', float32, callback)
self.theta= rospy.subscriber('theta_values', float32, callback)

self.extreme = (self.x - self.y) + ((self.x * self.y) * cos(self.theta))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done was wrong, you could try something to similar to bellow,

```
import rospy 
from std_msgs.msg import Float32 

class Handler():
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.subscriber('x_values', Float32, self.callback_xvalues)
        rospy.subscriber('y_values', Float32, self.callback_yvalues)
        rospy.subscriber('theta_values', Float32, self.callback_zvalues)
         self.extreme_pub = rospy.publisher('extreme/results', Float32, queue_size = 10) 

        self.x = None
        self.y = None
        self.theta = None 

    def callback_xvalues(self, data):
        self.y = data
    
    def callback_yvalues(self, data):
        self.y = data

    def callback_zvalues(self, data):
        self.y = data
        if((self.x is not None) and (self.theta is not None)):
            self.extreme = (self.x - self.y) + ((self.x * self.y) * cos(self.theta))
            info = Float32()
            info.data = self.extreme
            self.extreme_pub.publish(info)


rospy.init_node('extreme_values', annonymous=True)

node_ = Handler()
```

`rospy.subscriber` does not return anything, however when messages come corresponding callback, i.e., callback_xvalues, triggered, so your logic should be implemented inside one of those call backs, i.e., callback_zvalues. Do not register a same callback for a different topic, it is not recommended. Let me know you get the idea

Comment: I was introduce the whole data in one callback file, thank you for the hint but I didn't Understand the last line node_ handler(). Also I added I publisher line 
```
self.extreme_pub = rospy.publisher ('extreme results', float32, queue_size = 10)
```
I added at the first of the code
what do you think ?

Comment: @MEKH check is this what you are looking for?

Comment: is it better in this way ?? because I tried to do it in another way see the answer below